# How to print SOAP response data separately in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, soap

Android code:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo propInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        propInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;

        // adding parameters
        request.addProperty("userID", "18");
        //request.addProperty("password", "iprint");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Log.e("Object response", "Before response ");

            resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            //SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();


            SoapObject returnObj = (SoapObject)resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty("return");

            //Integer id = Integer.valueOf(returnObj.getProperty("id");
            //String username = (String)returnObj.getProperty("value");
            Log.v("key", returnObj.getProperty(2).toString());

            //log.v("values", username);
            Log.e("Object response",""+resultsRequestSOAP);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("error", e.toString());

        }
```

**Now I'm getting this out :**

```
getProfileResponse{
    return=Map{
        item=anyType{key=firstName; value=Donette; }; 
        item=anyType{key=lastName; value=Foller; }; 
        item=anyType{key=company; value=; }; 
        item=anyType{key=address1; value=34 Center St; }; 
        item=anyType{key=address2; value=; }; 
        item=anyType{key=city; value=Hamilton; }; 
        item=anyType{key=state; value=41; }; 
        item=anyType{key=postcode; value=45011; }; 
        item=anyType{key=country; value=1; }; 
        item=anyType{key=telephone; value=513-570-1893; }; 
        item=anyType{key=mobile; value=513-549-4561; }; 
        item=anyType{key=fax; value=513-570-1893; }; 
    }; 
}
```

**But I need output like this:-**

```
firstName,Donette lastName,Foller .. .. .. fax,513-570-1893;
```

Comment: separately means.? can you elaborate more.?

Comment: Please don't post question in caps. Use proper sentence case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SoapObject returnObj = (SoapObject)resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty("return");

    SoapObject finalReturn;
    for(int i=0;i<returnObj.getPropertyCount();i++){

        finalReturn= (SoapObject) returnObj.getProperty(i);

        Log.v("key", finalReturn.getProperty(0).toString()+" "+finalReturn.getProperty(1).toString());

    }
```